# FileReader producing a NPE

Tags: java, android, java-io

I have a file stored locally on my device that I read from perfectly fine if I don't reboot the phone.  When I reboot and read the logs, new FileReader throws an NPE; why?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Before filereader");
        fr = new FileReader(ABS_FILENAME);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Before BufferedReader");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String current;

        Log.d("DEBUG", "About to read file");
        while((current = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Exception thrown: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Problem closing file reader");
        }
    }
    return null;
```

The above code happens in a broadcast receiver.  ABS_FILENAME is a string that denotes a file.  That file is written to periodically in an Activity once something is clicked:

```
// in an onClick that gets invoked
try {
            String line = myKey + " " + myValue;
            fw.write(line);
            fw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(fw != null)
                    fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

// elsewhere in the activity
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    try {
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }
        ABS_FILENAME = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
        fw = new FileWriter(myFile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: I think there are some syntax errors in the code you posted; please fix

Comment: the ... wasn't the error btw, it's the extra closing brace behind catch

Comment: Is it a temp file that gets deleted when the device reboots? Is it a file on the SD card that is temporarily inaccessible after rebooting because the media scanner is running?

Comment: Also, is ABS_FILENAME a string or a File object?

Comment: the file is written to internal storage(the data/data/) directory, so it shouldnt get deleted unless the app is uninstalled: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Please show the full code where you're creating the file.

Comment: And please, always, post the stack trace.

Comment: Where and how is FILENAME initialized?

Comment: static final String FILENAME = "myFile.txt"; inside the activity.  This is the same as ABS_FILENAME in the broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
new FileReader(ABS_FILENAME)
```

really produces a `NullPointerException,` clearly `ABS_FILENAME` must be null.